# Multiple Select query in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

963 rows in user table 
872 rows in videos table

In user table (fbid,name) are column names
In video table (fbid,etc..) are colum names.

Using below query, I am fetching name from user table by providing fbid from video table. Below query is only returning 791 rows but it should return 872 instead.

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
$q = "SELECT * FROM videos GROUP BY fbid ORDER BY score DESC, id ASC";
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0): 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)):
        $fbid=$row['fbid'];

        $q1 = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE fbid=".$fbid."";
        $r1 = mysqli_query($conn,$q1);
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)):
            $name=$row1['name'];
            ?>

            <?php
            $counter++;
        endwhile;
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: its facebook id, it should be same. across 2 tables

Comment: I'm not familiar with colon syntax. Does it offer some advantage over curly brackets?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is 'never execute a query inside a loop'. However, in this instance, you don't even need a loop - a join will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT v.* 
     , u.name
  FROM videos v
  JOIN users u
    ON u.fbid = v.fbid
  ORDER 
    BY v.score DESC
     , v.id ASC;
```

Comment: This is only professional-grade advice on the page, but an explanation is called for.

Comment: @mickmackusa You want me to recall what I was talking about 3 years ago? I don't even know what I said yesterday.

Comment: You know what I mean.  Just explain why nested/iterated queries are bad and why a JOIN is advisable.  My SO philosophy doesn't permit me to upvote correct answers if they are code-only posts.

Comment: @mickmackusa Unfortunately, my SO philsophy prevents me from dredging up ancient history,

Comment: Good Stackoverflow knowledge is timeless.

Answer (score -1):

I modified the code for your inquiry

```
<?php

$counter = 0;
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `videos`  ORDER BY `fbid` ASC";
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0): 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)):
$fbid=$row['fbid'];

$q1 = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `fbid`= $fbid ";
$r1 = mysqli_query($conn,$q1);
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)):
$name=$row1['nombre'];
echo $name . "<br/>;
?>

<?php
$counter++;
endwhile;
endwhile;
endif;

echo "Total " .$counter;
?>
```

if you go 791 results may be because some video fbid table is not in the table check how many users this query

```
SELECT count(fbid) FROM `videos` where  fbid NOT IN(SELECT fbid FROM `user`);
```